# Difference between using has and !has in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

What is the difference between using `has()` and `!has()` in vimscript?

Comment: Negation of the check?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you sir.

Comment: `!` has same meaning that `not` in many languages. In `boolean` context it changes between `true` and `false`.

Comment: `==` and `!=` ; `exists('..')` and `!exists('..')`; `has()` and `!has()`.. you have got it, right?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't.   Maybe I'm over thinking it.

Comment: I think this is a valid question because of all the other myriad uses of `!` in vimscript! !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not that you're overthinking it, just that you haven't encountered `!` in programming languages before. It's pretty straightforward, though -- here's a quick explanation.

If you want to do something based on a condition, you use an `if` statement, right? For example,

```
if has('relativenumber')
    echo "Your Vim has the relative number feature!"
endif
```

If you want to do something if that condition is *not* true, you put a `!` before your condition. (this is called "negating" a logical condition)

```
if !has('relativenumber')
    echo "Your Vim does NOT have the relative number feature."
endif
```

You can use that in other case too. Take this, for example:

```
if x > 3
    echo "x is greater than three"
endif
```

You have to include parentheses to negate it though. (Order of operations!)

```
if !(x > 3)
    echo "x is less than or equal to three"
endif
```

This is equivalent to

```
if x <= 3
    echo "x is less than or equal to three"
endif
```

Comment: Okay now it makes sense.  Maybe I am getting ahead of myself a bit.  I'm just unable to hone on a situation where I would have to negate a value.  Keep in mind I just picked up Vim about 2 months ago.

Comment: It's not so much a Vim thing as a programming thing. You'll probably need that at some point, and now you'll know what to do. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: A little bit unrelated: I'm using Vim7.4 and using has('relativenumber') did not work for me. What *did* work: if exists('&relativenumber').